# Custom Body Class from URI

Tags: php, css, parsing, uri

I'm working on how to get a custom class into my body tag. I'd like to parse the URI and drop each part of the URI into the class as a separate string. This is a far as I've gotten. I've got the URI parsed and placed into the body class, but as a single string separated by /'s instead of spaces.

Also, I need the IF statement to add "home" if the URI is simply "/". Unfortunately, my current IF statement blows up the whole page. :-(

```
<?
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = trim($url, '/');
    if $url = '' {
        $url = 'home';
    }
    endif;
?>
<body class="<?=$url?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?
  $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $url = trim($url, '/');
  $url = str_replace ("/", " ", $url);
  if ($url == '') {
    $url = 'home';
  }
?>
<body class="<?=$url?>">
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! You rock!

Comment: As an aside, it does kill me a little inside that all I needed to do was wrap the condition in parenthesis. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use regular expressions.

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = trim($url, '/');
    if (preg_match("/^\\/?$/", $url)) {
        $url = 'home';
    }
    endif;
?>
```

`"/^\\/?$/"` this is regular expression

- `^` - means beggining of string
- `$` - means end of string
- `\\/` - it's `/` sign, but it has to be escaped by `\\`
- `?` means that sign before is optional

It will make match when REQUEST_URI will be empty, or it would contain only `/` sign.

Comment: Unuseful regular expression because you just did trimmed the var $url

Comment: OP asked about modification of if statement, to allow / sign, and this is the answer for his question. Btw - useless, not unuseful.